# How to dynamically fill in column values (avoiding loops) in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a way to dynamically fill in NA values in columns with the value in the previous column, using dplyr and avoiding loops.

I am working on inflation data for this problem, and I have provided a dummy dataset (see below), which is a small sub-set of the data that I have.

I have tried using `mutate_at()` but I am unsure how to get the function argument to refer back to the previous column.

```
dummy_data = tibble(Country = c("UK", "USA", "Canada", "France"),
                    `2020` = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0),
                    `2021` = c(0.03, 0.03, NA, NA),
                    `2022` = c(NA, 0.04, NA, NA))
```

The outcome expected is that the NA values will be replaced with the previous year's value, on a country by country basis. I know that this can be achieved using a loop, but ideally I want to keep it in the tidy pipe format.

```
result = tibble(Country = c("UK", "USA", "Canada", "France"),
                    `2020` = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0),
                    `2021` = c(0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0),
                    `2022` = c(0.03, 0.04, 0.03, 0))
```

Comment: Perhaps `lag` with `fill` is what you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
dummy_data = tibble(Country = c("UK", "USA", "Canada", "France"),
                `2020` = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0),
                `2021` = c(0.03, 0.03, NA, NA),
                `2022` = c(NA, 0.04, NA, NA))

res <- dummy_data %>% gather(year, value, -Country) %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% fill(value) %>% 
  spread(year, value)

#####

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Country [4]
  Country `2020` `2021` `2022`
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Canada    0.03   0.03   0.03
2 France    0      0      0   
3 UK        0.02   0.03   0.03
4 USA       0.03   0.03   0.04
```

Comment: Thanks! So this works for the dummy data but not for the real one, but I realised that the full dataset is not a tibble. Is this a possible issue?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Does it throw an error, does it give incorrect values?

Comment: Yeah ok so apologies for that - it was just not running (with a cryptic coercion error) but I figured out that the issue was that the data has NAs in the country list, and since that was a character it was treating them as duplicated names.

Sorry for the unhelpful comment before. This works perfectly now! Thank you :)

Comment: Ah ok :). Great!